# Why is Spark much faster at reading a directory compared to a list of filepaths?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a directory in S3 containing millions of small files. They are small (<10MB) and GZ, and I know it's inefficient for Spark. I am running a simple batch job to convert these files to parquet format. I've tried two different ways:

```
spark.read.csv("s3://input_bucket_name/data/")
```

as well as

```
spark.read.csv("file1", "file2"..."file8million")
```

where each file given in the list is located in the same bucket and subfolder.

- I notice that when I feed in a whole directory, there isn't as much delay at the beginning for the driver indexing files (looks like around 20 minutes before the batch starts). In the UI for 1 directory, there is 1 task after this 20 minutes which looks like the conversion itself.
- However, with individual filenames, this time for indexing increases to 2+ hours, and my job to do the conversion in the UI doesn't show up until this time. For the list of files, there are 2 tasks: (1) First one is listing leafs for 8mil files, and then (2) job that looks like the conversion itself.

I'm trying to understand why this is the case. Is there anything different about the underlying read API that would lead to this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. spark assumes every path passed in is a directory
2. so when given a list of paths, it has to do a list call on each
3. which for s3 means: 8M LIST calls against the s3 servers
4. which is rate limited to about 3k/second, ignoring details like thread count on client, http connectons etc
5. and with LIST build at $0.005 per 1000 calls, so 8M requests comes to $50
6. oh, and as the LIST returns nothing, the client falls back to a HEAD which adds another S3 API call, doubling execution time and adding another $32 to the query cost

in contrast,

1. listing a dir with 8M entries kicks off a single LIST request for the first 1K entries
2. and 7999 followups
3. s3a releases do async prefetch of the next page of results (faster, esp if the incremental list iterators are used). one thread to fetch, one to process and will cost you 4c

The big directory listing is more efficient and cost effective strategy, even ignoring EC2 server costs

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Let's say now that the 8mil files are distributed across multiple buckets and I only have a manifest file of all the paths to work with. In this case is there any workaround except trying to do a mass copy of all the files to a directory, and then using the directly directly?

Comment: you could seriously consider writing your own bit of scala to take that manifest and generate the list of files directly. after all, that's what "manifest" table formats -iceberg, hudi, delta lake do.